# Mean square convergence and $L^2$ convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I feel that these 2 things are necessarily always the same thing?
Because $L^2$ convergence can be a path-wise property only, however, mean square convergence is not.

Am I missing something though?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We have $E(|X_n-X|^2)=\int_\Omega|X_n-X|^2=\lVert Xn-X\rVert_2$. So as you mentioned, they are the same thing.